# How to edit forms to show fields from second model? And How iterate through manytomany field?

Tags: python, django, forms

I've created shop. I have two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=40)
    cost = models.FloatField(verbose_name="price")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Shop(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Nazwa", max_length=40)
    budget = models.FloatField(verbose_name="kwota")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I created forms.py file:

```
class ShopForm(forms.ModelForm): 
        product = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),required=True) 
        name = forms.CharField(max_length=15, label='Name')
        budget = forms.FloatField()

        class Meta: 
                model = Shop
                fields = ('product','name', 'budget')
```

Now I have something like that:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/boLIq.png]

What must I change to add cost of product next to this product? I have no idea but I think it is so simple...

## And second question:

When I want show details of Shop I don't know how to iterate through products. 
For example when i want show name of this Shop I add

```
{{ shop.name }}
```

when i do

```
{{ shop.product }}
```

I get an error

```
StopIteration at /shop/1/

No exception message supplied
```

I know it is problem because it is ManyToManyField but how create solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the first question, u may try to create your form without django forms with standard html form elements, probably there is a solution for your case but I dunno how to handle with django forms.

for second question,
u should use this:

`{% for p in shop.product.all %}
{{p.name}}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: i tried this second but it does not show anything more on site